# Removing entries from a dictionary based on values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with character-integer key-value pair. I want to remove all those key value pairs where the value is 0.

For example:

```
>>> hand
{'a': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'q': 0, 'u': 0}
```

I want to reduce the same dictionary to this:

```
>>> hand
{'m': 1, 'l': 1}
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: see this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447494/best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-a-python-dictionary

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
>>> { k:v for k, v in hand.items() if v }
{'m': 1, 'l': 1}
```

Or, in pre-2.7 Python, the [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor in combination with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
>>> dict((k, v) for k, v in hand.iteritems() if v)
{'m': 1, 'l': 1}
```

Comment: Note that this removes all values that evaluate to `False`. This is subtly different if you have non-integer values as well.

Comment: @Lattyware: It looks to me like OP only has integers as values... I can only work with what I get :)

Comment: using `.items` instead of `.iteritems` can be very inefficient for larger data sets.

Comment: @Don that depends on the version of Python you use. I'm usually assuming the newest version unless otherwise specified. Agreed though for my second example

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for the info, I spend so much time in 2.7 I actually didn't know about that change. Good stuff

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to create a new dictionary, you can use this:

```
>>> hand = {'a': 0, 'i': 0, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'q': 0, 'u': 0}
>>> for key in list(hand.keys()):  ## creates a list of all keys
...     if hand[key] == 0:
...             del hand[key]
... 
>>> hand
{'m': 1, 'l': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: This is not allowed in Python 3: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: @bugmenot123 try `for key in list(hand.keys()):`

Comment: Thank you! I ended up with that solution myself but had forgotten I posted here. :)

Comment: You can use `list(hand)`, no need to explicitly call `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 11):

```
hand = {k: v for k, v in hand.iteritems() if v != 0}
```

For Pre-Python 2.7:

```
hand = dict((k, v) for k, v in hand.iteritems() if v != 0)
```

In both cases you're filtering out the keys whose values are `0`, and assigning `hand` to the new dictionary.

Comment: IMO: better than Niklas' answer due to use of `iteritems`

Answer (score 4):

A dict comprehension?

```
{k: v for k, v in hand.items() if v != 0}
```

In python 2.6 and earlier:

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in hand.items() if v != 0)
```