# Compare dictionary list values to the list of list values using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, difference

I have a dictionary values and list of list values. I need to compare the list values with the dictionary values and get the matched data with key and value pairs.

My dictionary:

```
res = {
    'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'],
    '19hyHnlzDMEDJ9N5': ['#ffcc66', '#FFFFFF'],
    'TByXB1YzYSJW2kXO': ['#7A7FBC', '#807CC4'],
    'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']
}
```

My list of list values:

```
diff_tolistoflist = [
    ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'],
    ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']
]
```

Expected output:

```
test = {
    'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'],
    'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']
}
```

I need to compare dict values and list of values to get the similar data with key and value pair.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
also make sure to provide some input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Removing entries from a dictionary based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158599/removing-entries-from-a-dictionary-based-on-values)

Comment: This is not my question. This is to take difference between dictionary having list values and list of another values

Comment: Checking if an item is in a list is a fairly basic thing to do: [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571635/7851470). And combining this check with the code in the duplicate target should be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension which is quite easy to read:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in res.items() if v in diff_tolistoflist}
print(d)  
# {'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'], 'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the the list item with dict val_list

```
test = {}
for key, val in res.items():
    if val in diff_tolistoflist:
        test[key] = val
```

Result

```
>>> test
>>> {'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'], 'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']}
```

Comment: You don't need that second loop. Just test ```if val in diff_tolistoflist:```.

Comment: @accdias, indeed, I have updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: No worries, mate.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are unique, we can invert our dictionary:

```
reversed_dict = {tuple(res[key]): key for key in res}
```

Keys in the dictionary need to be mutable, so we had to convert them to tuples.

Then we can do a simple lookup of values:

```
final_result = {}
for v in diff_tolistoflist:
    k = reversed_dict.get(tuple(v))
    if k:
        final_result[k] = v
```

I've used `dict.get` so that it doesn't throw an exception if something's wrong.

```
>>> final_result
{'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'], 'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']}
```

This solution is case-sensitive. That means, `f` and `F` are considered different.  To make it case-insensitive, you can convert string to lower when reversing the dictionary and later do the same with the `diff_tolistoflist` (when declaring it or when looking up the values in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've user Filter function.

```
print dict(filter(lambda x:x[1] in diff_tolistoflist,res.items()))

Result:{'cXboTHyIeZaof6x7': ['#de6262', '#ffb88c'], 'utTtWdchE2T6vUF5': ['#A3DAC3', '#8BD0D4']}
```