# How to delete any value of a key in python using dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example:
a = {1:'hello' , 2:'bye'}

suppose I want to delete the element 2:'bye' through its value 'bye' , so can anyone help me by giving  a piece of code.

thank you

Comment: What do you mean "through it's value"? You mean that all you have is the value? Well, then you have to find the key corresponding to that value. This will be a linear time operation (unless you create a reverse mapping, which of course, will require more memory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing entries from a dictionary based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158599/removing-entries-from-a-dictionary-based-on-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for what I know you can do it like this

```
for i in a: # the dictionary
 if a[i] == 'bye':
   del a[i]
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: This is a bad idea, as deleting while iterating generally leads to problems. See the duplicate.

Comment: well you can do this then a.pop(i)

Comment: thanks mate. this really helped me