# How to remove dictionary key with known value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume python dict:

```
mydict = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}
```

I know one of the values:

```
value = 200
```

How to remove the `'b': 200` pair from the dict? I need this:

```
mydict = {'a': 100, 'c': 300}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a dictionary called `dict`, it will overwrite the builtin.

Comment: You're right, it is just a pseudecode. Renamed it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an item from a Python dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447494/best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
for key, val in list(mydict.items()):
    if val == value:
        del mydict[key]
        break # unless you want to remove multiple occurences
```

Comment: Is it ok to modify the dict that I currently iterate through? Is this why `mydict.items()` are used?

Comment: In python3 this solution fails(`RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`) because mydict.items() return an iterator not a list like python2.

Comment: @pbacterio runs fine for me in 3.3.2 - which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i'm testing without the `break` statement to remove multiple occurrences. In this case i sugest wrap `mydict.items()` with `list` to prevent this exception.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`dictionary comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Note that (as jonrsharpe has stated) this will create a new dictionary which excludes the key:value pair that you want to remove. If you want to delete it from your original dictionary then please see his answer.

```
>>> d = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300}
>>> val = 200
# Use d.items() for Python 2.x and d.iteritems() for Python 3.x
>>> d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v != val}
>>> d2
{'a': 100, 'c': 300}
```

Comment: Note that this will build a new dictionary excluding the value, rather than removing it from the original dictionary

Comment: OK, this is correct. One followup question: This seems to be iterating over the whole dict. Can't I iterate to a point where the first value is found?

Comment: If you know that only one key:value pair is in your dictionary then I would suggest jonrsharpe's answer (or similar creating a new dictionary). You can then `break` on the first instance. In any case you'll need to use a proper `for` loop rather than a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over every items(), either with dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() if predicate(value)}
```

Or modifying the existing dictionary:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if not predicate(v):
        del my_dict[k]
```

Comment: This is it! I can `break` after the del. This is what I want, thanks.

Comment: @pythonishvili: no, it's just a regular python function or expression that you'll need to define

Answer (score 0):

The simplest i found:

```
for key in [k for k,v in mydict.items() if v==200]:
    del mydict[key]
```

Comment: i didn't downvote you, but you're unnecessarily creating a list comprehension that you're only iterating through. should use a gen expr instead. i upvoted you back to zero

Comment: i don't use a generator because can produce a error if you try to remove multiple occurrences.