# Removing all the keys with multiple occurence of values in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
dct={'a':3,'b':1,'c':1,'d':1,'e':2,'f':2}

for key in dct.values():
    #code
```

I cannot find a way to delete all the keys that have same values, my output should be:

{'a':3}

Basically i only want to have a dictionary with multiple occurrences of values removed, the value is not specifically 1 or 2 it could be any #

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to remove an item from a Python dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447494/best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-a-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this dict comprehension:

```
new_dct = {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if list(dct.values()).count(v) <= 1}
```

This won't delete from your original dictionary, but will generate a new dictionary with only the keys and values where the value is not duplicated in your original dictionary.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>*: Note that in Python 3.x the [`values()` method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) of `dict` objects returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), while in Python 2.x it [returns a normal `list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) object. Hence the need to call `list()` on it here in order to use the `count()` list method, since OP is using Python 3.x. If you are using Python 2.x, you can simply remove the `list()` call, and call `count()` on `dct.values()` directly.</sub>

Comment: elethan i get error saying dict_values has no attribute count

Comment: @CAVS try `dct.values()` (the same call you use in your example), not `dict.values()` or `dict_values`.

Comment: Aaahhh, Python 3, sorry. Give me a moment to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution

```
dct={'a':3,'b':1,'c':1,'d':1,'e':2,'f':2}
d = {} 
allu = [];
lulu = [];



for  k, v in dct.items():
  if v in allu:
    lulu.append(v)
  allu.append(v)   

d = dict(dct)
for k,v in d.items():
  if v in lulu:
    del dct[k]

print(dct)
```