# find particular value from list of dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
s = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3},{'a':2},{'a':1}]
```

remove duplicate value pair
and I want a list of dictionaries like:

```
s = [{'a':1},{'a':3},{'a':2}]
```

Comment: `s = [{'a': d.get('a', None)} for d in s]`

Comment: related: [Remove an item from a dictionary when its key is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447494/remove-an-item-from-a-dictionary-when-its-key-is-unknown)

Comment: @RoadRunner just wanted to point that default value can be passed in second parameter.

Comment: @RoadRunner, np.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension with filter `a`:

```
s = [{k: v for k, v in x.items() if k =='a'} for x in s]
print (s)
[{'a': 1}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 2}]
```

Comment: Why to iterate over whole dict instead of getting value by key?

Comment: @OlvinRoght - It was my first idea ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension adding new dictionary entries only if `'a'` is contained:

```
[{'a':d['a']} for d in s if 'a' in d]
# [{'a': 1}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
s = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3},{'a':2}]
s=[{'a':d['a']} for d in s]
# [{'a': 1}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list of singleton dictionaries with only `a` keys, you can do this:

```
>>> [{'a': d.get('a')} for d in s]
[{'a': 1}, {'a': 3}, {'a': 2}]
```

But this just seems more suitable for a list of tuples:

```
>>> [('a', d.get('a')) for d in s]
[('a', 1), ('a', 3), ('a', 2)]
```

From the docs for [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a [Key Error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).